# Create a column based on the aggregation of values from multiple column at multiple row indexes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to translate a technical analysis operator from another proprietary language to python as using dataframes, but I got stuck on a problem that seems rather simple, but I can't get to solve the pandas way. To simplify the problem let's have the example of this dataframe:

```
d = {'value1': [0,1,2,3], 'value2': [4,5,6,7]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

which result in the following dataframe:

[image: dataframe]

What I want to achieve is this:

[image]

which in Pseudocode I would achieve in the following way:

```
value1 = [0,1,2,3]
value2 = [4,5,6,7]
result = []

for i in range(len(value1)):
    calculation = value1[i] * value2[i]
    lookback = value1[i]
    for j in range(lookback):
       calculation -= value2[j]
    result[i] = calculation
```

How would I tackle a this in a dataframe context? Because the only similar approach that I found in the documentation is the usage of https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html# but there is no mentioning of interacting/manipulating the series contained in the columns/rows.

Comment: `value1` column's values are the indexes. Is this your actual case or `value1` can have any value?

Comment: in this case yes they are the same as indexes, but it's incidental, might be any integer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
df['result'] = df.value1 * df.value2 - (df.value2.cumsum() - df.value2)
df
```

**Output**

```
   value1   value2  result
0   0       4       0
1   1       5       1
2   2       6       3
3   3       7       6
```

**Explanation**
We are calculating cumulative sum for value2 and subtracting the current value2 which in total is subtracted by the product of value1 and value2.

Answer (score 1):

This solution should work even if the first column `value1` has random integers and not increasing integers from 0, and follow the pseudocode provided by the OP.
You should just ensure that any value in `value1` is a valid integer for the dataframe (that is, no integer grater than the amount of rows in the dataframe, which is also required by the pseudocode).

```
import pandas as PD

d = {'value1': [0,1,2,3], 'value2': [4,5,6,7]}
df = PD.DataFrame(data=d)

csum2 = df["value2"].cumsum()
df["sum2"] = [csum2[i] for i in df["value1"]]
df["result"] = df["value1"] * df["value2"] - df["sum2"] + df["value2"]
df.drop("sum2", axis=1, inplace=True)
```

To explain: I save in an additional column `"sum2"` the result of the inner loop in the pseucode `for j in range(lookback):` so that I can then perform the main operation to get the `"result"` column.

At the end `df` is:

```
   value1  value2  result
0       0       4       0
1       1       5       1
2       2       6       3
3       3       7       6
```